# Magento 1 image upload error for product admin windows only

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

On a mac I can upload images in the admin area for products without an issue. However, on a windows machine I get an "http image upload error" I've looked in .htaccess. Please help

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?